# Creating a SQL Server view in a specific database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, view

This is a very stupid question, but I cant seem to add a view to a specific database, it gets added to the default master, which is no acceptable.

I have tried this in SQL Server 2008:

```
 CREATE VIEW MyDB.Test AS     
  Select Orders.CustomerID    
  From Orders
```

I get the error msg:

> The specified schema name "MyDB" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it.

Thanks!

Comment: 1. does the **schema** `MyDB` exist? 2. Do you have permissions to use it - inparticular create objects etc?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if you do have access try:

```
Use MyDb
Go

CREATE VIEW Test AS
Select Orders.CustomerID
From Orders
```

Comment: I do have access, but I now get the message 'CREATE/ALTER VIEW' does not allow specifying the database name as a prefix to the object name.

Comment: Apologies - you have solved it. I didnt copy and paste everything

Comment: Note that I took the "MyDb." prefix off the create. The "Use" switches you to the MyDb database, then you just Create the view Test with no DB prefix.

Comment: lol, ok! Crossed messages.